# Goutte Submit form without a submit button

Tags: php, laravel, goutte

I am trying to submit data in this form:

https://www.trademe.co.nz/property/insights/

I get

> The current node list is empty.

```
$client = new Client();

$url = 'https://www.trademe.co.nz/property/insights/';
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
$form = $crawler->filter('form')->form();
$crawler = $client->submit($form, array('search-input' => '2 queen Street'));
```

Comment: try change get for post